# In hls,How to use #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE for client?

Tags: http-live-streaming

4.3.3.3.  EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE
   The EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE tag allows synchronization between
   **different Renditions of the same Variant Stream or different Variant
   Streams** that have EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tags in their Media Playlists.

what`s Variant Streams? 
I think means one of Master Playlist,like http://example.com/low.m3u8 right?
    Master Playlist

```
>        #EXTM3U
>        #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1280000,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=1000000
>        http://example.com/low.m3u8
>        #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2560000,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=2000000
>        http://example.com/mid.m3u8
>        #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=7680000,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=6000000
>        http://example.com/hi.m3u8
>        #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=65000,CODECS="mp4a.40.5"
>        http://example.com/audio-only.m3u8
```

1. each time server remove a EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY from the playlist you
   must increment the EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE
2. each time server removea segment from the playlist you must increment

> ```
>      #EXTM3U
> #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0
> #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
> #EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
> #EXT-X-VERSION:2
> #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
> #EXTINF:8,
> fragment1.ts
> #EXTINF:8,
> fragment2.ts
> #EXTINF:8,
> fragment3.ts
> #EXTINF:8,
> fragment4.ts
> #EXTINF:8,
> fragment5.ts
> #EXTINF:8,
> fragment6.ts
> #EXTINF:4,
> fragment7.ts
> #EXT-X-DICONTINUITY
> #EXTINF:8,
> fragment0.ts
> ```

when i playback hls live,server reload m3u8(playlist) and remove #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY,EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE plus one,what do client should?
I can`t understand why EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE tag can synchronization in different Variant
   Streams.please

Comment: Is this the same as [How to use EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE when creating an infinite HLS stream that loops over same fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51274444/868014)?

Comment: not yet，I want to kown why that the #EXT-X-DICONTINUITY will end up at the top of the playlist after some time and when it drops out the EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE must be incremented by 1 as well.